# PHP Coding $ variable

Tags: php, html, variables

I want to place a HTML code inside a $ variable. So, I have a "sidebar.html" file, which has just got various "{$test1}" "{$test2}" and so on.

I can't work out how to add the HTML code to that.

So in short, I want to have {$fleet} in the first HTML file, and in my php code, I need something like

```
$fleet = <div class="sidebar-content">
<div class="sidebar-header">Find a Fleet</div>
    <div class="sidebar-link">
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=ObsidianFleet">Obsidian Fleet</a>
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=startrekfreedom">Star Trek Freedom</a>
    </div>
<div class="sidebar-link">

</div>
</div>

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a `$` variable? Variables in PHP are all indicated by `$`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to assign a string value?

Try [heredocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$fleet = <<<EOF <div class="sidebar-content">
<div class="sidebar-header">Find a Fleet</div>
    <div class="sidebar-link">
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=ObsidianFleet">Obsidian Fleet</a>
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=startrekfreedom">Star Trek Freedom</a>
    </div>
<div class="sidebar-link">

</div>
</div>
EOF;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
$fleet = <<<'PHP_STR'
<div class="sidebar-content">
<div class="sidebar-header">Find a Fleet</div>
    <div class="sidebar-link">
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=ObsidianFleet">Obsidian Fleet</a>
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=startrekfreedom">Star Trek Freedom</a>
    </div>
<div class="sidebar-link">

</div>
</div>
PHP_STR;
```

Comment: 14 secs slower than ComFreek... :) yet, **+1** for a good answer!

Comment: @alfasin Yup haha, but still slightly different (nowdoc vs. heredoc), both work depending on if the OP wants interpolation or not :)

Comment: @alfasin except his is more correct based on the original (hard to understand) question.

Comment: To add a point: Paulpro's solution will process faster because no parsing is involved, but as always: depends on the use case ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell PHP that it is a string. Wrap the HTML with the single quote `'` character:

```
$fleet = '<div class="sidebar-content">
<div class="sidebar-header">Find a Fleet</div>
    <div class="sidebar-link">
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=ObsidianFleet">Obsidian Fleet</a>
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=startrekfreedom">Star Trek Freedom</a>
    </div>
<div class="sidebar-link">

</div>
</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

As a string:

```
<?php
$fleet = '<div class="sidebar-content"> 
<div class="sidebar-header">Find a Fleet</div>
    <div class="sidebar-link">
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=ObsidianFleet">Obsidian Fleet</a>
    <a href="./index.php?a=profile&u=startrekfreedom">Star Trek Freedom</a>
    </div>
<div class="sidebar-link">

</div>
</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fleet = "<div class='sidebar-content'>
<div class='sidebar-header'>Find a Fleet</div>
    <div class='sidebar-link'>
    <a href='./index.php?a=profile&u=ObsidianFleet'>Obsidian Fleet</a>
    <a href='./index.php?a=profile&u=startrekfreedom'>Star Trek Freedom</a>
    </div>
<div class='sidebar-link'>

</div>
</div>

}";
```